# Qt layouting: default size constraints vertically, setFixedSize horizontally

Tags: qt, layout

I'm developing an app with a complex hierarchy of widgets and layouts, but in short it has a central widget with a formulary as upper widget and a `QScrollArea` as buttom widget (by means of a `QVBoxLayout`).

That `QScrollArea` represents a list (grid layout indeed) of `QPushButton`s which can contain a huge number of buttons (or not).

I want my app fits the following constraints:

- Both (form and list) consume all available horizontal space, redistributing its contents to fill all horizontal space (nor `SpaceItem`s neither contents margins).
- Both must save as vertical space as possible, in order to make "lines" close to each other.

I've solve partially my problem making use of `setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)` on the form, which shrinks it vertically, but also horizontally, causing that both, list and form, have different widths, wich doesn't look like very well.

How can I achieve that? I mean, how can specify something like `grow horizontally to fill the widget but shrink vertically has much as possible`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a spacer as the last item to the layout:

```
gridLayout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(10, 10, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding), lastrow, 0);
```

Comment: That is a sort of "margin" at right of the widget. I want to redistribute the space to fill all available horizontal space.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you use grid layout. Add the spacer to a separate row instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

If you know how many columns you will have (and it doesn't change), [insertStretch()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch) in the last column (although it might give you the same effect as using a spacer).

```
int columnCount = gridLayout()->columnCount();
gridLayout->insertStretch( columnCount(), 1 ); // Default stretch for other
```

Note that this will resize your buttons to the size Qt thinks they should be unless you are explicitly changing their widths.